# MySQL row subquery (multiple columns) with CASE (not in where-clause)

Tags: mysql

I want to retrieve *two columns* from the same table, but **only** if a certain column in the current row isn't set. With just one column to retrieve, there is no problem. Once I need another column, it appears that I need another subquery with another case-clause, but that seems really ineffective. I've never used Joins before, but I'm thinking it's probably really complicated with the case clause?!

I thought the beauty of it was that it actually only executed the (as I heard) wasteful subquery in the few cases when it's needed.

In the docs, I found that comparisons using `ROW()` are apparently possible. Is there an equivalent for retrieving the columns with `AS`?

Thank you for any hints, if it only works with Joins, please give me a push in the right direction since they seem kind of complicated and with the case clause it's probably gonna be a mess if I just go ahead.

**Ruben**

```
SELECT id, bekannt, (

CASE WHEN bekannt =  ''
    THEN (
        SELECT bekannt
        FROM vokabeln AS v2
        WHERE v2.id = vokabeln.hinweis
        LIMIT 1
    )
    ELSE NULL 
    END
) AS lueckentext, (

CASE WHEN bekannt =  ''
    THEN (
        SELECT hinweis
        FROM vokabeln AS v2
        WHERE v2.id = vokabeln.hinweis
        LIMIT 1
    )
    ELSE NULL 
    END
) AS lthinweis
FROM vokabeln
WHERE nutzer =  'test'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd code it as:

```
  SELECT
    v1.id, v1.bekannt, v2.bekannt AS lueckentext, v2.hinweis AS lthinweis
  FROM 
    vokabeln AS v1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN vokabeln AS v2
    ON (v1.bekannt='' AND v2.id = v1.hinweis)
  WHERE
    v1.nutzer='test'
```

Comment: __Thanks a lot__, this doesn't look as complicated as I expected. I didn't know joins could be conditional. Maybe I'll get it right myself one day.

Comment: Yep, the `ON` subclause of any `JOIN` clause can be any boolean expression (and the `OUTER` join puts the `NULL`s in place of the second table's fields in the `SELECT` list, if for some row in the first table no row in the second table satisfies the `ON` condition).

Comment: Can I somehow specify the _default_ table to assume, so I don't have to specify `v1.id`, but `id` will be non-ambigously resolved to `v1.id` (only `v2.something` still specified)?

Comment: @Ruben, not in portable Sql, though if you're willing to toss out of the window the ability to ever upgrade or port your code in exchange for a microscopic amount of convenience, there might be ways in very specific Sql dialects.

Comment: Well the convenience wouldn't be exactly microscopic, the query is of course a little larger. But ok, I just thought there might be something like FROM vokabeln AS DEFAULT (well of course something different, but anyway.
If I use my two CASE-statements, would I lose a lot? It actually seems worth it, if I look at how the where-clause gets generated…

Comment: @Ruben, measure the performance with your approach and mine (on data sets large enough to be representative of your actual usage, and on the _real_ query): most likely the `OUTER JOIN` will be substantially faster than the nested queries, but without access to your data set and the actual way you want to set up indices, I can only guess, while you can **measure**.